# Multi-layer prepositional phrase

Tags: syntactic-analysis, prepositional-phrases, noun-phrases, complements

I am having trouble picturing the structure of this preposition phrase

> from the point of view of generative syntax (PP)

My attempt to run it down goes like this:

> from (preposition) + the point of view of generative syntax (NP)
> the (DET) + point of view of generative syntax (nominal)

And I am stuck here, because I am uncertain if it should be

> [point of view] [of generative syntax](PP complement)

or

> point [of view [of generative syntax]]

Namely, is the PP complement "of generative syntax" attached to the noun "view"? It feels weird if that's the case. Because that way it would mean "of view of generative syntax" constitutes a PP and "view of generative syntax" an NP, but that doesn't appear to be true.

Also I think the NP "point of view" is headed by "point" instead of "view", so shouldn't the complement attach to the head noun "point" or the entire NP? [BillJ's answer here](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/31500/whats-the-difference-between-a-modifier-and-a-complement/31504#31504) specifies licensing as the criterion for complements. So in such a case where the core that is followed by an NP complement is an NP itself, which is the noun that does the licensing or permitting?

Comment: You are partly right. See my answer for a detailed analysis.

Comment: from the point of view of generative syntax (PP) = same as: from the point of view of [whatever]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *... from the point of view of generative syntax.*

The whole expression is a PP.

The PP "from the point of view" is analysed as prep + NP complement, where the head noun "point" has the PP "of view" as its complement.

The PP "of generative syntax" then functions as a complement within the larger PP, so we have a PP functioning within a larger one.

We know it's a complement because if it is dropped the expression becomes ungrammatical (we can't say *"from the point of view of". "Of" requires a complement to complete the PP).

[image]

Comment: I learned the part about determining if a PP is a complement from your Linguistics SE answer, so that part is clear. Regarding the phrase structure though, just so I understand your answer clearly, so "of generative syntax" is a complement of the PP "from the point of view", not the NP "the point of view"? Also would I be wrong if I said "of generative syntax" is licensed by "point", the head noun of the NP "point of view"?

Comment: @EddieKal I've added a tree diagram to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since "point of view" is a lexical unit (non analysable) ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/point-of-view?q=point+of+view)) it is not correct to consider "of view …" as a prepositional phrase. Accordingly, the parsing is as follows ("point of view" is treated as a noun and there is just one embedding.

- from [the point of view [of generative syntax]]

Were it not the case of "point of view" being a lexical unit there would be two embeddings.

- from [the point [of view [of generative syntax]]]